# Python threading with 4000 threads

Tags: python-3.x, stack, windows-10, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

Looking at picking up stock data using urls from nasdaq. For 4000 stocks am thinking of doing each in a thread so 4000 url threads. Has anyone tried this ? Does it overload windows stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using [`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) with default max workers as too many threads will cause a giant overhead.

Max workers default to `(processor_count) * 5` which is good in your case I believe.

A client using `asyncio` is also an option but it's quite a bit more complicated.